# Filtering data using age group in django

Tags: django, filter

I want to filter my products based on for what age group they are intended to. My plan of doing that is using a boolean field and filter the products by that. I have a dropdown menu which lists the different age groups and when a person clicks on one, a page will be displayed with the products which have boolean true for that age group.
Here is my models.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, upload_to='images/')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    detail = RichTextUploadingField()
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    child = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    teen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    adult = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Is this the way I should do it? If it is the case should I use 3 different views.py for each boolean or is there any efficient way?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need 3 `views` to show this. You can get the value user submits via a form like this `request.GET` if you didn't specify any `method` attribute in the form or for `POST` request you can get the data using `request.POST`.
Assuming you are using pure Django with functional-based `views`. Then your view will look like this.

```py
def get_products(request):

    # getting the gender group you passed via form
    gender_group = request.GET.get("gender_group")

    # assuming you are passing `child`, `teen` and `adult` through from drop-down value
    user_products = Products.objects.filter(**{gender_group: True})

    return render(request, "you_template_name.html", {"products": user_products})
```

Assuming you html form will be something like this one.

```html
  <form method="get">
        <!-- you other fields -->
      <select name="gender_group">
        <option value="child">Child</option>
        <option value="teen">Teen</option>
        <option value="adult">Adult</option>
      </select>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mubashar javed you are correct. I just added two things and it worked.

```
 <Form action="{% url 'get_products' %}" method="get">
  <select name="gender_group">
        <option value="child">Child</option>
        <option value="teen">Teenager</option>
        <option value="adult">Adult</option>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </select>
 </Form>
```